# How do I detetct whenever the Lichess API Rating History updates in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Im building a project that displays a bunch of different lichess stats from my account and Im not sure how I can detect whether the api data changes and then fetch the new data

I honestly came here because I have absolutely no clue what to do or what to start. I am using React and Node-Fetch to get the API data. How can I detect when the API data changes and then fetch. If it's not possible, what other solutions might kind of work?

Comment: If they don't support some kind of websocket you need to poll.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.